# Hide a css-made dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a dropdown menu with css. Here is the HTML code:

```
<li class="menu" id="menu">
  <div class="dropdown">    
    <div class="col1"> ...
```

here is the css:

```
.dropdown {
   visibility:hidden;
   /*...*/
}

#menu li:hover .dropdown{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

This works perfectly. In jQuery I handle the click event for the links in this menu and I want to use jQuery to hide the dropdown whenever the user clicks on a link so it goes away.
I tried these both (note: I haven't used these together.):

```
$('.dropdown').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //didn't work

$('.dropdown').hide(); //didn't work either
```

they both hide the menu but the problem is when they hide it, I don't get the menu again whenever I hover the mouse over the item.

Comment: check out www.sc-pa.com, turn off javascript, is that what you want?

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain I see nothing wrong with it...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what is actually happening is when you you set `$('.dropdown').css('visibility', 'hidden');` on the element, it adds this to the style attribute of the element, inline (you can check this with Firebug). So the CSS

```
#menu li:hover .dropdown{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

doesn't have any effect because inline styles take precedence. `.dropdown` elements will always be set as `hidden` now.

Comment: I didn't use both of the methods at the same time. I tried `$('.dropdown').css('visibility', 'hidden'); ` but it didn't help either. Shouldn't it fix the problem?

Comment: So what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what happens when the mouse is hovering the button and what happens when it's not. Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".dropdown").hover(function() {
        /* hovering actions */
    }, function() {
        /* non-hovering functions */
    });
});
```

Comment: Haven't I do this using CSS? I think doing it again won't be required using jQuery (maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: I do my menus like this. Set the default non-hovered state in CSS and then leave the rest up to jQuery. I only use a CSS hover action in <noscript> tags, just in case someone with blocked JS comes along.

Comment: That is just a matter of personal interest. My question is why doesn't this (`$('.dropdown').css('visibility', 'hidden'); `) work? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's because jQuery's hide() method uses the rule "display:none" over that elemenent, in this case ".dropdown", to hide it, therefore, by definition, the "visibility" can't work on an element that has the rule "display:none" assigned to it.

Use jQuery to make the dropdown effect instead of a bunch of CSS rules.

Comment: Well I want my site work on the clients that don't have JS enabled.

Comment: So why doesn't `$('.dropdown').css('visibility', 'hidden');` work?